# How to re-link collections to scene

Tags: linked-data, collections

To clean up my scene, I used <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> > *Unlink* in the *Outliner*, but now I want the collections back.

I can find them by switching to the *Blender File* context in the *Outliner*, but the <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> > *Link to Scene* doesn't appear to do anything.

*Instance to Scene* makes something that acts like a Collection Instance, so I can't edit the contents.

I also can't click and drag, or copy paste.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open a second outliner view and drag and drop the collection back to the view layer.

Here from Orphan Data to View Layer:

[image]

Comment: No collections appear in Orphan Data, but it does appear in Blender File.

Dragging it to the scene from there does make it appear in the (view layer) outliner, but the text is greyed out, and I cant see the object in my viewport.

Comment: Okay, I had to go N-Panel -> Colletions and enable it there. I think that worked!
Thank you!

Comment: Not allowed to comment, but I would like to add to the answer.
To link to existing axes (left after unlinking any instances), drag the orphaned object, then hold Ctrl before dropping it on the axes. This applies all transformations to the linked object again.